# $match by aggregated hierarchy in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I try to `$match` previously aggregated by `$graphLookup` records using and-regex.

I've tested it in mongoldb shell and it works! But same query ruined through `mongoose` return empty set.

(disclaimer: it's overlapping my previous question [How to match aggregated ($graphLookup) elements in MongoDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48964626/how-to-match-aggregated-graphlookup-elements-in-mongodb/48964714#48964714), but occasionally I need more flexibility than like match, so I decide to ask once again)

Let say, I have:

```
{ "_id": 1, "name": "Dev", final: false }
{ "_id": 2, "name": "Eliot", "reportsTo": "Dev", final: false }
{ "_id": 3, "name": "Ron", "reportsTo": "Eliot", final: false }
{ "_id": 4, "name": "Andrew", "reportsTo": "Eliot", final: false }
{ "_id": 5, "name": "Andron", "reportsTo": "Eliot", final: false }
{ "_id": 6, "name": "Asya", "reportsTo": "Ron", final: true }
{ "_id": 7, "name": "Dan", "reportsTo": "Andrew", final: true }
{ "_id": 8, "name": "Don", "reportsTo": "Andron", final: true }
```

By call aggregate

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {$match: { final: true }},
  {$graphLookup: {
    from: "employees",
    startWith: "$reportsTo",
    connectFromField: "reportsTo",
    connectToField: "name",
    as: "reporters"
  }},
  {$match: ???}
])
```

What regex-match do I need to add to get this:

```
{"_id": 7, "name": "Dan", "reportsTo": "Andrew", final: true,
  "reporters": [
    { "_id": 1, "name": "Dev", final: false },
    { "_id": 2, "name": "Eliot", "reportsTo": "Dev", final: false },
    { "_id": 4, "name": "Andrew", "reportsTo": "Eliot", final: false }
  ]
},
{"_id": 8, "name": "Don", "reportsTo": "Andron", final: true,
  "reporters": [
    { "_id": 1, "name": "Dev", final: false },
    { "_id": 2, "name": "Eliot", "reportsTo": "Dev", final: false },
    { "_id": 5, "name": "Andron", "reportsTo": "Eliot", final: false }
  ]
}
```

As I suggest, it must be properly solved by applying `$match-$and-$regex`, due to my case limitations (I've need to generate regex rules on-fly), I have no abilities to prepare slashed regex pattern.

```
{$match: 
  {$and: [
    {"reporters.name": {$regex: 'Andr(?:ew|on)'}}, 
    {"reporters.name": {$regex: 'Eliot'}}
  ]}
}
```

Comment: Did you try {$regex: /And/} syntax ?

Comment: i guess you dont have documents with this values. mybe you want to use $or and not $and ?

Comment: Wait a minute, I'll try to define my input and output more clearly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected.

```
db.employees.aggregate([
  {$match: { final: true }},
  {$graphLookup: {
    from: "employees",
    startWith: "$reportsTo",
    connectFromField: "reportsTo",
    connectToField: "name",
    as: "reporters"
  }},
  {$match: 
    {$and: [
      {"reporters.name": {$regex: 'Andr(?:ew|on)'}}, 
      {"reporters.name": {$regex: 'Eliot'}}
    ]}
  }
])
```